# How to put an empty variable inside of div in a php file and then define it in another php file

Tags: php, html, variables

I'm a PHP newbie and learned the basics. Currently I'm creating a website using PHP and HTML. 
I want to place an empty variable inside of div. So, when I use the file with include 'content.php' inside index.php and then write below echo $var_content = 'hello2'; (for testing purposes), it works but the defined variable is not inside of  but outside of this area. 
Here is my code of content.php:

```
 <?php
$var_content = '';
echo '<main>
<div style="max-width:1000px; margin:auto;">
<div style="background-color:rgba(238,234,232,0.6);margin:8px 0 0 0; padding:1px 20px 35px 20px;">'. $var_content .'
</div>
</div>
</main>';
?>
```

Codes inside of index.php:

```
<?php
    include 'header.php';
?>

<?php
    include 'content.php';
    echo $var_content = 'hello2';
?>

<?php
    include 'footer.php';
```

What am I doing wrong? I included a screenshot for more details. https://prnt.sc/kqk1nc

Comment: Thanks! At first I thought i had to define the variable inside content.php first, then place it inside div and then define it again, but I realized I overwrote it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.php - set the variable here:

```
<?php
    // set variables
    $var_content = 'hello2';

    // includes
    include 'header.php';
    include 'content.php';
    include 'footer.php';


?>
```

content.php - echo only here, do not overwrite `$var_content = '';`

```
<?php
    echo '<main>
    <div style="max-width:1000px; margin:auto;">
    <div style="background-color:rgba(238,234,232,0.6);margin:8px 0 0 0; padding:1px 20px 35px 20px;">'. $var_content .'
    </div>
    </div>
    </main>';
?>
```